# Return Download File from Controller .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to make a Controller to Download a file from server. After searching around, I make this function in my controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DownloadController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("ExportData")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ExportData()
    {
        FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(@"D:\Sample.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream tempMs = new MemoryStream())
        {
            fs.CopyTo(tempMs);
            bytes = tempMs.ToArray();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return File(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Data.xlsx");
    }
}
```

But when I access the url from browser, it just loading non stop. If I stop the API, the loading will stop and show the download failed with network error.

The file is not a big file so not suppose to be the problem. Am I missing something?

*Additional info, I don't know if this related but this is my Configure function on Startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });

    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: @mjwills the file is just around 107kb. On chrome it's not downloaded until I stop the API. After I stop it, it will show download failed.

Comment: you could at the very least put a breakpoint before the download, see how long that part took up until then, and then make sure the file is loaded into that byte array as you expect.

Comment: @JohnLord Actually I did, when I put break point, it run successfully until the function end without any error. But on the browser, it still loading non stop even the function already complete.

Comment: Does it help if you set the `Position` of the `MemoryStream` to 0 before the `File` call?

Comment: @mjwills After I run (F5) from Visual Studio, I just open the url of the controller on the browser. for example `https://localhost:44342/api/download/ExportData`

Comment: @mjwills oh setting the Position to 0 works. Thanks. You can put it on the answer..